# NoReverseMatch at / Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

I`m using Django 1.10 and I getting this error:

**NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'views.product_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []**

This is my index.html template:

```
{% for pr in product %}
                <li>
                    {{ pr.pk }}
                    <a href="{% url 'views.product_detail' pk=pr.pk %}">
                        {{ pr.name }}
                    </a>
                    || {{ pr.description }} || <img src="{{ pr.image.url }}">
                </li>
{% endfor %}
```

My Main project urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('products.urls') ),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My App urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.hello_world, name='hello'),
    url(r'^product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.product_detail,name='product_detail'),
]
```

My views.py is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Product

# Create your views here.
def hello_world(request):
    product = Product.objects.order_by('id')
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = {
        'product': product
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def product_detail(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    template = loader.get_template('product_detail.html')
    context = {
        'product': product
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

the error message is:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdQeL.png)

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: You shouldn't be using URL tag like that. Instead, use the permalink decorator. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you've included the product URLs. You've terminated that including pattern with `$`, so nothing afterwards will ever match. When including, never use a $.

```
url(r'', include('products.urls') ),
```

Answer (score -1):

NoReverseMatch means that Django hasn't matched your requested URL with any URL you have in your `urls.py`.

It looks like `r'^$'` wouldn't find anything because the pattern has no room to include any text. Change `r'^$'` to `r''` or `r'^products/'` in your project urls. That way, your urls would look like this:

```
'/products/product/1/' # For product_detail
'/products/' # For views.hello_world
```

Comment: Hi Kris, I change r'^$' to r'^/$'  and now the message is                      **Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in Shoppy.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^/$ [name='hello']
products/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='product_detail']
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.**   Thanks for your help